# Insert error while inserting data to PostgreSQL with python psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql

```
 try:
            for i in (0, nCount):
                query = "INSERT INTO students (Name, ID, Birth) VALUES (%s %d %d);"
                data = ('Y', 2, 9)
                cur.execute(query, data)
                conn.commit()

 except:
            print("I can't INSERT into students")
```

`Connect to database` and `select` operation are work but `insert` operation is not.
I use `PostgreSQL` and `pgAdmin4`
And create database use `pgAdmin4`
The DB structure is `Name(text)`, `Id(integer)`, `Birth(integer)`

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Solve
* Change type of all columns to text (not text[]).
 * Change column name in DB to small letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my best knowledge you missed `,` in values clause. I think you need write smthng like `values (%s,%d,%d)`